# Magento Customer Address temlates per Store View

Tags: php, magento, e-commerce

I'm trying to use customer address templates in Magento for a custom module I'm currently working on. What this module does is it fetches the address of an order and formats it based on the template set in System->Configuration->Customers->Customer Configuration->Address Templates.

For example:

```
   echo $address->format('html');
```

The problem is that I would like Magento to load a different template based on a different Store View, the Store View that corresponds with the store in which the order was placed.

I've tried to backtrace the format($type) function in the Magento core files (app/code/core/Mage/Customer/Model/Address/Abstract.php) to understand how this function works, but I can't seem to figure out how to load a different configuration based on the correct Store View.

I've worked with Magento (from 1.7.x and up) for the past year, creating modules and custom adjustments to core functionality, so I somewhat know my way around in Magento's design pattern, and am always willing to learn.

Thanks in advance,

AJ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who are also looking for an answer, I've eventually been capable of solving this problem for now, as follows:

I've copied the Abstract.php file to the local code base, to a location corresponding with the original location, to allow me to override the Magento Core file. After that I've modified the format($type) method to allow for an extra parameter to be set, containing the Store in which an order was placed. Once set, it will allow for loading the correct Addres template, corresponding to the Store View. If not set, it wil just be disregarded, so all other Magento functionality relying on this method will still function properly.

This might not be the best solution, but it is sufficient for the time being.

Answer (score 0):

Is this not working if you change the configuration scope (in top-left of the page) when you are in System -> Configuration ?
So you uncheck "use default" checkbox and set the wanted value for your store view.

Comment: That is exactly what I thought, but it does not. Even though I've set different templates per Store View, unchecking the "use default" check box, it keeps loading the default template. (I know it is the default, because when I change that, the output does change.)